# Get item by ID in Sitecore 6.5

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6

I am on Sitecore 6.5.

The below code is working fine but I don't understand how. The `GetItem()` method has six overload functions where it takes string values as just item paths.

In this case it's taking in an id as a string and correctly returning the item (the location is Sitecore droplink field). Am I missing something?

```
private Sitecore.Data.Items.Item LocationItem
{
    get
    {
        return Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Item["Location"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The string parameter for `GetItem()` can be an ID or a Path.
Both will work.

Comment: intellisense does not showing Id. May be something wrong with just mine.

Comment: Intellisense shows GetItem(string path), but that can be string containing an ID or path. They should have named it pathOrId :)

Answer (score 3):

Sitecore can take a path or an ID as the string. `Item["Location"]` will contain a GUID (as the field type is a droplink), which you're currently retrieving as a string.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected functionality.
You can pass both ID or path to this method, however documentation may not be clear on this.